# conversion from 'size_t' to 'rapidjson::SizeType'

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, size-t, rapidjson

I have this c++ example code:

```
void test()
{
    rapidjson::Document doc;
    doc.SetObject();

    const std::string source = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";   
    rapidjson::Value source_val;
    source_val.SetString( source.c_str(), source.length(), doc.GetAllocator() );        
}
```

And at compile time, on x64 platform, I get this warning:

> warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from `size_t` to
>   `rapidjson::SizeType`, possible loss of data

How can I correctly convert from a string's length (`size_t`) to rapidjson SizeType?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://rapidjson.org/namespacerapidjson.html#a44eb33eaa523e36d466b1ced64b85c84):

> RapidJSON uses 32-bit array/string indices even on 64-bit platforms,
>   instead of using `size_t`. Users may override the SizeType by defining
>   [RAPIDJSON_NO_SIZETYPEDEFINE](http://rapidjson.org/group___r_a_p_i_d_j_s_o_n___c_o_n_f_i_g.html#ga250603aa9e2a12429b25ba0c8108ad4f).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I correctly convert from a string's length (`size_t`) to rapidjson SizeType?

The implicit conversion that you're already using is a correct way to convert from `size_t` to `rapidjson::SizeType`.

A warning doesn't necessarily mean that your program is not correct.

In this case, it simply warns that `rapidjson::SizeType` cannot represent all values representable by `size_t`. Therefore if you try to use a longer string than can be represented by `rapidjson::SizeType`, you will get unexpected behaviour.

If you do want to support such strings, then you must override the `rapidjson::SizeType` as described in the documentation in the other answer.

> can I get rid of this warning?

An explicit cast typically convinces the compiler that you didn't convert by accident: `static_cast<rapidjson::SizeType>(source.length())`

Comment: I know that a warning is not an error, but can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Yes, the static_cast is a solution, but I consider the rapidjson documentation of defining RAPIDJSON_NO_SIZETYPEDEFINE more elegant. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just remember that actually using so long strings will make the xml unparseable on 32 bit systems.